# Cannot access http-server since installing Landscape

Tags: server, apache2, landscape

I have a small problem with my Apache server. Normally I would access my home-brew Ubuntu server via my browser with it's local IP adress like this:

```
http://192.168.0.76/owncloud
```

But it stopped working when I installed the Landscape server quickstart package according to [this help page](https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/QuickstartDeployment15.11) with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install landscape-server-quickstart
```

Plenty of packages were installed and it all seemed to work. Sadly I no longer can access the Ubuntu server with it's local IP adress. It get's redirected to the hostname of the server like this:

```
http://HostName/owncloud
```

I no longer can access the server and/or the /owncloud-Folder
I know that this is a stupid question to ask here but I wasn't able to find help via Google.
I already located that Landscape has an `/etc/landscape`-dir and apache has an `etc/apache2/`-dir but I wasn't able to resolve the problem by trying to change the config files

How should I proceed?
removing landscape-server-quickstart didn't worked because that hasn't restored the previous config files.

Answer (score 1):

The quickstart package assumes it owns apache I'm afraid. It gets rid of the default vhost file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` directory.

You should be able to restore your other sites by inspecting what's missing in that vhost file, but anytime quickstart is installed or upgraded, it will take over again.

quickstart is meant as an easy and quick way to sample landscape, but more permanent deployments should consider other installation options listed in https://help.landscape.canonical.com.